# Build a custom calendar in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

I have to build a **calendar** like the one in the picture. I saw that the library eiste `Tapku Library` but is different from what I get. Do you have suggestions?!

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/SVCalendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`klazuka_Calendar`**:

https://github.com/klazuka/Kal

[And Also This is best site for all custom Controls.](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar)

Comment: Kal is out of date.. mind putting up [this list](https://cocoapods.org/?q=calenda) ?